# Crash on opening groups of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, list, arraylist, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview

I am trying to do a dinamical generation of groups in **ExpandableListView**

I declared an array of list which represent the list elements for every group

```
List<MarkCell>[] voti_materia;
```

and I inizialized it in this way (10 is the max number of groups, subjects.getCount() is the number of element in a spinner)

```
voti_materia = new ArrayList[10];

for(int i=0; i<subjects.getCount();i++){
     voti_materia[i] = new ArrayList<>();
     listDataHeader.add(subjects.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
}
```

It works, it generates the right groups on the screen and if I try to open the first group of the list it works, but if i try to open the other groups the app crash for **NullPointerException**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.aesolutions.schooltools.diary_adapter.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount(ExpandableListAdapter.java:75)
                                                                             at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:563)
                                                                             at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:688)
                                                                             at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:693)
                                                                             at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:653)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3305)
                                                                             at android.widget.AbsListView$4.run(AbsListView.java:4228)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

on this function of the **ExpandableListAdapter**

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}
```

_listDataChild is declared as

```
private HashMap<String, List<MarkCell>> _listDataChild;
```

I don't understand why it crash... someone can help me? Thank you all

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint and walking through making sure `_listDataChild` has the correct values in it

Comment: @AESolutions You should post the full stacktrace. But from what you have posted you should debug what is being returned in getChildrenCount(). Particularly if there is nothing to get from _listDataChild

Comment: ok I posted the full stacktrace... It shows me that _listDataChild is size 1 (it should be size 4), this is the error but I don't know why it is only 1 element

Comment: Where are you filling `_listDataChild` ?

Comment: It's automatic... when I create the adapter it calls that function

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

I forgot to put

```
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), voti_materia[1]);
```

inside the for with index i :(

```
for(int i=0; i<subjects.getCount();i++){
        voti_materia[i] = new ArrayList<>(i);
        listDataHeader.add(subjects.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), voti_materia[i]); // Header, Child data
}
```

Thank you all!